# Jenkins automated iOS build has SwiftSupport folder missing

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, jenkins

Currently I'm having an issue that when jenkins executes a job to generate a .ipa to submit to testflight, Apple sends me the following email:

> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "XXXXX". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:
>
> Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is missing. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.

I opened the .ipa that was uploaded and it's true this folder isn't there.
So I tried doing the build manually... I used the same workspace that jenkins uses to generate the builds, and I manually generated a build to upload to AppStore and everything went well...

What might be the problem with the automated build? Is there a step that jenkins might be missing?

Is anyone having the same issue??

Answer (score 3):

#### Archive the application

```
xcodebuild \
-workspace "${WORKSPACE_FILE}" \ # only if you are using workspace
-scheme "${SCHEME_NAME}" \
-sdk "${TARGET_SDK}" \
-archivePath "${PROJDIR}/Build/${SCHEME_NAME}.xcarchive" \
-configuration Release \
archive
```

#### Export the archive to an ipa

```
xcodebuild \
-exportArchive \
-archivePath "${PROJDIR}/Build/${SCHEME_NAME}.xcarchive" \
-exportOptionsPlist "${PROJDIR}/exportOptions.plist" \
-exportPath "${PROJDIR}/Release"
```

#### exportOptions.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>app-store</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you specifying the -exportOptionsPlist option on your xcodebuild command?

See `xcodebuild -help` for the available keys, but you probably want a plist with at least he method key set to "app-store", like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>app-store</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Are you saying adding "method/app-store" to the app's plist?  Or is this a different plist file?

Comment: @Pedro This is a different plist file that's passed to xcodebuild using the -exportOptionsPlist switch